# how can i get Date of Expiry from my Barcode Scanner?

Tags: iphone

i am new in this Field.I have implemented BarCode Scanner.I have got the Proper Value of Barcode and Barcode Type.Now Is there any way to find the Date of Expiry using that value.Please help me i don't have any idea about it.Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the barcode is normally just a number, it depends on what this number references.

For most products available commercially it is either EAN 8 or EAN 13. To see the breakdown of what an EAN number represents have a look at the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/BarCodeAX.aspx?msg=2580704

Unless the barcode that you are scanning specifically has the expiry date contained in it you will need to load the related information from somewhere else

Comment: ok!But this tutorial is not in Objective-c.i want some sample code using that i can get the Date of Expiry...

Comment: The link that I gave you was to show the structure of EAN 8 and EAN 13 barcodes. These are the barcodes normally used on sellable products. From the link you will see that the expiry date is not contained in the barcode. You will need to get access to the database where the product is stored to find that out